# Concatenate two dataframes of unequal dimensions in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes of unequal rows. I want to concatenate first 20 rows of one dataframe to first 5 rows of another dataframe and perform this recursively till the end of both the files.

Sample data:

```
df1
col1    col2
1       0.1     
2       0.2
3       0.3
4       0.4
5       0.5
6       0.6
20      0.10
21      0.01
22      0.01
23      0.01
24      0.01
40      0.01
100     0.90
```

```
df2
col1   col2
1      0.1
2      0.2
3      0.3
4      0.4
5      0.5
6      0.6
7      0.7
8      0.8
9      0.9
10     0.4
```

Output

```
col1    col2
1       0.1     
2       0.2
3       0.3
4       0.4
5       0.5
6       0.6
20      0.10
1      0.1
2      0.2
3      0.3
4      0.4
5      0.5
20      0.10
21      0.01
22      0.01
23      0.01
24      0.01
40      0.01
6      0.6
7      0.7
8      0.8
9      0.9
10     0.4
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is change index in both `DataFrame`s by integer division with `//`, [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) together, sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and last create default index by `reset_index`:

```
N1 = 20
N2 = 5

#if not default RangeIndex in both
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)

df1.index //= N1
df2.index //= N2

df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index(kind='mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Sample**:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(20)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(100, 110)})
#print (df1)
#print (df2)

N1 = 5
N2 = 3

df1.index //= N1
df2.index //= N2

df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index(kind='mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
print (df)
      a
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5   100
6   101
7   102
8     5
9     6
10    7
11    8
12    9
13  103
14  104
15  105
16   10
17   11
18   12
19   13
20   14
21  106
22  107
23  108
24   15
25   16
26   17
27   18
28   19
29  109
```